# Filtering using terms for function_score in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am trying to filter out results of a cosine similarity using `terms`. This is the query I am using?

```
{
    "size": 15,
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": {
                        "terms": {
                            "id_": [
                                "1","2", "999"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "script_score": {
            "script": {
                "source": "cosineSimilarity(params.query_vector, 'emb_vector') + 1.0",
                "params": {
                    "query_vector": [

                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "_source": {
        "includes": [
            "title",
            "body",
            "id_",
            "text"
        ]
    }
}
```

What I want is only those docs with the id  1,2 or 999 be returned. But, it is throwing the following error:

```
"reason": "[function_score] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",
                "line": 17,
                "col": 9
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the mapping:

```
{"mappings": {
  "properties": {
    "id_": {
      "type": "text"
    },
    "emb_vector": {
      "type": "dense_vector",
      "dims": 768
    },
    "title": {
      "type": "text"
    }, 
    "text": {
      "type": "text"
    }

  }
}
}
```

Comment: Try moving scipt_score inside the function_score object.

Comment: That worked. Thanks!